# Fastest way to get (i,j) indices of a value in a Python matrix array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

What is the fastest way to get all the (i,j) indices of the value 1 in the numpy array below?

```
import numpy as np 

arr = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
arr = np.array(arr)
arr
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

I have tried using nested for loops `for i for j` but that takes `O(n^2)` for larger datasets. I have also tried using `np.where(arr == 1)` but did not get (i,j) indices:

```
np.where(arr == 1)
(array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 2, 1])) # not (i,j) indices
```

What is a better or faster way to get the (i,j) indices?

Comment: `where` gives the indices - as a tuple of arrays.  That's really the most useful form, since it can used directly to index the array.  A list of tuples has to be applied one by one, much slower.

Answer (score 1):

The two arrays you get back are just the column/row index of each match.  You can simply zip first and second array together into tuples.

```
import numpy as np 

arr = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
arr = np.array(arr)    

d = np.where(arr == 1)
tuple(zip(d[0], d[1]))
```

Output

```
((0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1))
```

Comment: No problem feel free to accept the answer so other's may benefit.

Comment: Does np.where uses nested ```for i for j``` for loop under the hood? Or it uses some form of faster search like binary search? Tried looking at the source code and could not figure out... @Chris

Comment: `np.nonzeros` just runs through the while array (flattened) looking for `True` values.  Nothing fancy, just compiled.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having the indices as i-j pairs, use [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
ij = np.argwhere(arr == 1)
```

`ij` will be an Nx2 array containing an index pair in each row. You can still use the columns as a fancy index.

Otherwise, use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), which is what gets called when you do [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with a single argument:

```
i, j = np.nonzero(arr)
```

If your array is strictly zero or one, you don't need `== 0` in either case. Both functions look for non-zero elements.

Also, keep in mind that all these functions have a similar time complexity, which is `O(N)`, for `N` being the total number of elements in the array. Whether you use a numpy function or a nested `for` loop, at least one pass needs to be made over the array.

Answer (score 0):

So This is basically a simple array traversal problem and This problems will always take O(n^2) time.

So I feel it's ok to use loops here

INPUT:

```py
arr = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
arr = np.array(arr)


def method_1(arr):
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            if arr[i][j] == 1:
                temp.append((i, j))
    return temp


def method_2(arr):
    d= np.where(arr == 1)
    temp = []
    for i, j in zip(d[0], d[1]):
        temp.append((i, j))
    return temp


start_time = time.time()
method_1(arr)
end_time = time.time()

print(end_time- start_time)

start_time = time.time()
method_2(arr)
end_time = time.time()

print(end_time- start_time)
```

OUTPUT:

```sh
2.00271606445e-05          #Time taken by 1st algorithm
4.50611114502e-05          #Time taken by 2nd algorithm
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1)]
```

**NOTE:** Whenever you want to check the efficiency of an algorithm you can use time function